# The Reputation in Stack Exchange Data Dump is of SO

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, data-dump

I was going through the data dump at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange for Meta Stack Overflow. The `reputation` field in `Users.xml` seems to return the reputation of the User on Stack Overflow.

For example, Jeff Atwood's reputation comes to be 43,078 from the MetaSO dump. While the actual current reputations are: MetaSO: 276,369, SO:43,468

Moreover `Views` field shows 2,770 value. While the actual values are MetaSO: 73,422 SO: 376,594

References: https://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=accounts, https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood

Answer (score 8):

You've actually made a minor error that many people make.

This site is Meta Stack Exchange. Meta Stack Overflow is a completely different site and it uses the reputation of Stack Overflow as meta sites other than Meta Stack Exchange do not have their own reputation.

As such, the information in the data dump is correct.

For reference, [here's Jeff Atwood's Meta Stack Overflow profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood). As you can see, the reputation is identical to his Stack Overflow reputation.

Many years ago, the two sites were one, with Meta Stack Overflow being the network-wide meta. The decision was made to split the meta discussion of Stack Overflow away from general discussion and Meta Stack Exchange was created instead.

Comment: Could you tell me what does the `UpVotes` field mean? It says 105 for Jeff Atwood but that does not seem to be the total UpVotes he got. Is it the ones he casted?

Comment: Probably. His upvote count is visible on his activity page. The numbers aren't the same but they're close and the data dump isn't current.

Comment: @DakshShah see the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for most explanations what the fields mean.